# What causes this error when loading plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, spatialite, osx

After installing pyspatialite on my Mac two plugins fail to load with this error::
This plugin is broken
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2-spatialite'

I am fairly sure that the offending string '2-spatialite' is part of the version string associated with pyspatialite (2.6.2-spatialite.2.4.0-4)

The two plugins giving this error are Qspatialite and opengeo-explorer. What is weird is that the opengeo plugin does not use spatialite.

I assume that something in the plugin support is splitting the version string on '.' and expecting to get integers back.

Comment: sounds like this should be a bug report on the plugin bug trackers

Comment: I have reported it to the authors of both the plugins involved.

Comment: I actually strongly suspect that the problem is in QGIS code that loads the plugin.  I have been through the code of both plugins and neither appear to do any version checking.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is rather a packaging problem.

The package you mention is from the official python sources.

For Windows builds with OSGEO4W, the version number is 3.0.1-1, and it is installed by default.

According to this ticket for Ubuntu: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10099, pyspatialite is now part of python-qgis, so no need to install it separately. Maybe this is done for OS builds too.